# Printing above average times from race

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I'm trying to print out the times in my program that are equal to or above the average. When i add a `print()` to my method itself it works just fine, but when i print it from my main method it prints all the values it should except that it prints the last value twice. Before I was getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, i fixed the issue but apparently something is still off. I have been stuck on getting this to work for a while but cannot fix it! I've looked online and through a bunch of forums and tried to implement different suggestions but i still can't get it to work.

Literally any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MarathonRunner {

//Finding the average
public static double getAverageTime(int[] times) {
    int sum = 0;
    double average;

    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + times[i];
    }
    average = (double) sum / times.length;
    return average;

}

//Finding above Average 
public static int getAboveAverage(int[] times) {
    int aboveAverage = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

            if ((double)times[i] >= getAverageTime(times)) {

                aboveAverage = times[i];
                System.out.println(aboveAverage);

            }

        }

        return aboveAverage;
    }
}
```

Test/Demo

```
public class TestMarathonRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int times[] = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 275, 275, 243, 334, 412, 
  393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

System.out.println("The average time is: " +
     MarathonRunner.getAverageTime(times));

System.out.println(MarathonRunner.getAboveAverage(times)) ;
```

Prints

```
341
329
445
334
412
393
343
The average time is: 321.46666666666664
341
329
445
334
412
393
343
343
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print it from the main method it only prints the last Above average time, this is because that is what the getAboveAverage method is returning.

The reason it prints everything and then the last one twice is because you are printing them all in the getAboveAverage method, and then printing the last one again because it is returned to the main method.

If you change the main method to this it should only print them once:

```
public class TestMarathonRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int times[] = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 275, 275, 243, 334, 412, 
  393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

System.out.println("The average time is: " +
     MarathonRunner.getAverageTime(times));

MarathonRunner.getAboveAverage(times);
```

If you want to print them from the main method you could do this instead:

Make the getAboveAverage method return an ArrayList:

```
//Finding above Average 
public static List<Integer> getAboveAverage(int[] times) {
    List<Integer> aboveAverages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

            if ((double)times[i] >= getAverageTime(times)) {

                aboveAverages.add(times[i]);

            }

        }

        return aboveAverages;
    }
}
```

Then iterate through in the main method:

```
public class TestMarathonRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int times[] = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 275, 275, 243, 334, 412, 
  393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

System.out.println("The average time is: " +
     MarathonRunner.getAverageTime(times));

List<Integer> aboves = MarathonRunner.getAboveAverage(times);
for(int i : aboves){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, i thought my method was already set up to print all the times that were above average, not just the last, shouldn't i++ keep running through it though? I need to get it to print them all from the main,  i added print() to the method just to see if it was working.

Comment: Ok, in that case maybe you could make getAboveAverage return an array or list of ints containing all of times that are above average, and then iterate through them in the main method

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) Could you accept my answer it's right?

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks correct.. Do not return anything from `getAboveAverage` method if you are going to print it out.. If you want to return all the items that are greater than average then you need to return a list not integer.

To avoid printing the last item twice.. just remove the System.out.println from your test `System.out.println(MarathonRunner.getAboveAverage(times)) ;`